# jquery : How to unbind dynamically created elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have buttons created dynamically. I know that bind/unbind is only applicable for elements not created dynamically. To add functionality I use `.live()` which works perfectly. My problem is Idk how to remove the functionality. Please help.

Comment: have you tried .die()?

Comment: @Floradu88 yes and it didn't work.

Comment: I already solved it. The main reason I called the .die() method in document.ready without first calling .live(). I solved this by transferring all the .live() before all the .die(). Obviously someone has to live first before they die.

Comment: `live` is deprecated. Use `on` and `off` instead.

Comment: Can you show your sample code that How you solved your problem? Becaue I am having same issue but not get succeeded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `die()` function for this

Read http://api.jquery.com/die

Also in **Jquery-1.9** these `functions` are `removed`

For this you can use `on` and `off`

Read http://api.jquery.com/on and http://api.jquery.com/off

Answer (score 5):

You can use [die](http://api.jquery.com/die/) to remove handler previously attached by live.

> The [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event
>   handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in
>   preference to .live().

You can replace `live / die` with `on / off`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do your binding and unbinding in separate functions that you call after the elements are entered into the page. That way you have full control over what happens exactly when.

So first you create the element and then simply call the bindButton function. I have run into this problem quite often when working with Ajax and this solution is my absolute favorite.

```
function bindButton(){
    $('#newButton').click(function(){
        //do something
     });
```

And then you create a similar function to unbind that click event whenever you like.